# Transpose offsets of start index and end index

Tags: java, algorithm

Supposedly I have a given start index and an end index, I need to transforming these to positive values, and start index transposing to 0.

For examples:

```
(-5, -2) -> (0, 3)
(-2, 3) -> (0, 5)
(1, 10) -> (0, 9)
```

I can use a couple of `if` to achieve results, but is there an elegant one-liner to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the logic here? Aren't you just substracting the first "index" from both?

Comment: If you really need a one-liner, you may want to head over to [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a new index: `(0, last-first)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.abs` to find the index of the last element:

```
int adjustedFirst = 0;
int adjustedLast = Math.abs(first-last);
```

Comment: According to the provided examples there's no need for `Math.abs` - it would just be `int adjustedLast = last - first;`

Comment: @UnholySheep For some reason I was under the impression that the first index might be larger than the second index. If that's not the case, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the first index from bot indices

```
int secondIndex = secondIndex - firstIndex;
int firstIndex = firstIndex - firstIndex;
```

Calculate `secondIndex` first as you are changing `firstIndex` value.